# How to fix "404 Not Found" error when creating a WINDOWS_SAC node pool in a cluster (rapid release)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, windows-container

I'm setting up a cluster on `GCP` and trying to add a `Windows_SAC` node pool in it. A "Not found" error was return (`code=404`).

My project was added to the rapid release channel, and this cluster was set up with the `--release-channel rapid` flag from a whitelisted service account.

This cluster has alias IP enabled, an UBUNTU default node pool, and was created successfully, with master and node versions both `1.14.3-gke.9`.

When I tried to add a "Windows_SAC" node pool with the following commmand:

```
gcloud container node-pools create win-pool --cluster=NAME --image-type=WINDOWS_SAC --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --num-nodes=1 --verbosity debug
```

The following error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\container\node_pools\create.py", line 212, in Run
    raise exceptions.HttpException(error, util.HTTP_ERROR_FORMAT)
HttpException: ResponseError: code=404, message=Not Found.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.node-pools.create) ResponseError: code=404, message=Not Found.
```

Have anyone encountered similar issues? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: instead of using `--verbosity debug`, can you use the `--log-http` flag? 404 implies you are not hitting the right API

Comment: Did you get it to work?
I'm trying to follow https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-windows-containers-kubernetesengine/index.html#4 running the commands from there but I get the same error as yours.

Comment: The issue was not having access to the Windows node pool, which is even more exclusive than the rapid release channel access. You can submit a form to request access here https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfk6PAxUqQ0k08ByqU49yy8s1sLNivHLkbQ6ltxUZf49j3C0g/viewform but I have no luck so far. I did hear that this feature will be rolled out for rapid release users by the end of this month though.